# Can you have multiple httpd-vhost.conf files on Mac OS X 10.9+?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

I'm most likely switching to a vagrant set up in the near future, but for now, my vhost config file is getting very cluttered with all of the entries.  Can I have multiple vhost files?  I do not want multiple apache instances or virtual machines (yet).

/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: Related answer on the [Apple SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/37254).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split your config between several files. The `extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file is loaded from `httpd.conf` via `Include extra/*conf`, so you may create a `extra/httpd-vhosts1.conf`, `extra/httpd-vhosts2.conf`, etc.